# jQuery Datatables - add rows in a function that returns a Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Single Page Application in which I am trying to populate a JQuery Datatable with the results of an AJAX call. The AJAX call returns a Promise.

The code where I define the table and call the AJAX function to populate it is shown below. The data never appears in the table.

```
                    if ( ! $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#clients' ) ) {
                    table = $('#clients').DataTable({
                        "order": [],
                        retrieve: true,
                        "select": true,
                        select: {
                            style: 'single'
                        },
                        info: false,
                        lengthChange: false,
                        ordering: false,
                        "columns": [
                            {"data": "name"},
                            {"data": "dateofbirth"},
                            {
                                "data": "id",
                                "visible": false
                            }
                        ]
                    });


                clientMaintenance.getClientsForAccount()
                    .then(function (data) {
                        table.clear();
                        table.rows.add(data).draw();
                });
```

I can see that `data` in `getClientsForAccount.then` is a JavaScript array, so I don't understand why the data does not appear in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `columnDefs` instead of `columns`. You can find documentation on [how to use `columnDefs`here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs).